# Отправка POST запроса

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, post, ajax, get

Всем привет.
У меня есть несколько `<input>`´ов в HTML-коде.
Из них мне надо вытащить `value="значение"` и отправить его с помощью POST запроса.

```
<input type="text" name="MicL" value="" id="micl" readonly
                                       style="border: 0; width: 20px; color:#0099FF; font-weight:bold; display: inline-block;"/>
```

Вот как я получаю сам `value=""`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/audio",
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
        var audio = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("input[id='micl']").val(extractNumberFromDBVal(audio.MicL));
        $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider( "option", "value", extractNumberFromDBVal(audio.MicL));
```

Comment: headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}) + ({ "MicL" : ("#micl").val() }), я думаю так должно работать?

Comment: В вопросе вы пишите про POST, в таком случае измените
`type: "GET",` на `type: "POST",`

Comment: То, что я написал, это как получается сам `value=""`, т.е он у меня берется из JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Еслы не можете вытащить value, тогда вместо `$("input[id='authpass']").val()` напишите `$("#authpass").val()`.

Comment: `$("input[id='authpass']").val() напишите $("#authpass").val()` это мне еще надо.
____
Да и + немного не понимаю, как вытащить `value=""`.

Comment: Я же вам написал, как вытащить.

Comment: Да, только смотрите, то, что у меня в коде на счет `authpass`, мне надо для выполнения всех GET и POST запросов - это пароль. Теперь как дополнительное вытащить и `value=""` из другого `input=""`, но их много и у всех разные ID.

Comment: Тогда вместо "authpass" подставляйте другой id. Или вам нужно в цикле все выбрать?

Comment: Если я вставлю другой ID, то он не отправит пароль, и можно забыть вообще о выполнении JS.   
+ также 6 разных ID + authpass надо отправлять.

Comment: Извините, но я вас не понимаю. Я вам говорю в JS подставлять другой id для выбора значения из другого поля, я не говорю вам изменять его id в html.

Answer (score 2):

```
data: $("#formID").serialize()
```

Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте свойство [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/audio",
    data: {
        parameter1: $('input[name="par1"]').val(),
        parameter2: $('input[name="par2"]').val(),
        parameter3: $('input[name="par3"]').val(),
    },
    ...
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/audio",
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { "MicL" : $("input[id='#micl']").val(),
                    "MicR" : $("input[id='#micr']").val(),
            },
            cache: false,
            headers: ({"Auth-Secret": $("input[id='authpass']").val()}),
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            }
        })
    }, 1000);`не работает ;(

Comment: Что по сети передаётся — смотрели?

Offtop: изменения регулятора громкости не нужно передавать раз в секунду. Вместо этого слушайте события изменения, ползунка, и только тогда передавайте новое значение.

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).mouse( "_mouseDrag" );`  
или  
`$( ".selector" ).mouse( "_mouseInit" );`

и пробовал также прикручивать эту функцию, но не получается.
Можете помочь? Я не особо силен в jquery.

url: "/api/audio" - исправил, просто опечатка, но не помогло, не отсылаюся параметры.

Comment: Дистанционно не помогу. Смотрите, какие параметры отсылаются – откройте Developer Tools или что там у вас в браузере показывает, какие запросы уходят-приходят. Должно стать понятнее.

Comment: Ну, вот смотрите, я пишу 

    if $( "#slider-vertical_micl" ).mouse( "_mouseMove" ));
    ...

получаю ошибку:
>Error: cannot call methods on mouse prior to initialization; attempted to call method '_mouseMove'
 

>throw new Error( msg );